# How to Align four buttons at dead center in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios7

How do I align these four buttons to be at the center (horizontally and vertically) for the diff sizes of screens. I see different sizes and positions of the buttons when I run the project in the different size  of the simulator. Is there a way to make the four buttons to be at center (and same size) for ALL devices?

I don't have any experience with constrains, it has been a while since I used Xcode. I read tutorials about constrains for hours, but I still don't understand how to use it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJOyr.png)

Thank you and happy holidays :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/). Very simple to use, and it automatically manages the layout for the buttons.

Remove the existing constraints for your buttons, then select all four and choose **Editor -> Embed in -> Stack View**.

Add two constraints to center your stack view in the view, and you're done!

[image]

Comment: or use UIView as container to support < 9.0

Answer (score 1):

[image]Yes you can use Stack View, but it is only supported from ios 9, so if you are trying to have constraints below ios 9, follow below steps -

1. Add a UIView as container for your buttons, and add following constraints to it. (We will not give fixed height constraints to this view,let it determine its height intrinsically i.e we will use buttons to determine the size of container as buttons have their intrinsic size.)

   a. Align Center X to superview

   b. Align Center Y to superView

   c. Trailing and Leading space
2. Now add first button and add following constraints -

   a. Center horizontally in center.

   b. Top space from superview (as buttons and have its intrinsic size so we dont need to give height and width, it will calculate from its content)
3. Now for rest of three buttons add following constraints -

   a. Center horizontally with first button

   b. Add top and bottom space to all buttons with their respective top and button views (buttons). For last button i.e 4th add bottom space constraints with container view.

Note - Now that top button have top space constraints with container view and last button have bottom space constraints with container view and all remaining buttons are connected to each other with top and bottom space, this will determine the height of container view and your buttons will be always appear in center of screen for all size.

Below is the link for screenshot with all required constrints explained above.

[Screenshot with required constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/080UM.png)